# How can I actually see my data in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: macos, azure-data-studio

How can I actually see my data? I'm working with SQL and am creating views to be able to see the data. The views are accepted by Azure but don't actually do anything since they're not letting me see the data. I'm not talking about the ER Diagram or another schema visualization, I mean the ability to actually see a table with the data I've inserted inside of it.

I currently cannot access Windows and am working on Mac.

I've downloaded SandDance and "Schema Visualization" extensions, but neither of them are what I'm looking for. I just need something I can use that will actually show me the data that I'm working with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the data of a table directly in Azure Data Studio, you can follow the procedure below:

Double-click on the database, and you will get the homepage of the database with a list of tables. Go to the actions of the table, click on the three dots(...) to show actions, and select **Edit data** as shown below:

[image]

Then, you will be able to see the data of the table as shown below:

[image]